# Advanced Ajax Page Loader: Reload Bootstrap

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pageload

On my wordpress-site the blog page is different than the rest of the site. Therefore I built a second bootstrap.css and loaded it this way:

```
if( is_page_template('page-blog.php') )
{
    wp_enqueue_style('roots_bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/blog/bootstrap.css', false, null);
    wp_enqueue_style('roots_bootstrap_responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/blog/responsive.css', array('roots_bootstrap'), null);   
}else{
    wp_enqueue_style('roots_bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.css', false, null);
    wp_enqueue_style('roots_bootstrap_responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/responsive.css', array('roots_bootstrap'), null);
}
```

But I need to use Advanced Ajax Page Loader and of course it doesnt work anymore. Is there a way to let AAPL reload my script and not only that: Reload the right one depending on the page I'm on?